# How do you allow a program file access in order to save a chart image?

Tags: c#, .net, file

Given a string input of an existing file name I want to save whatever visual the chart object is showing at the time.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsGoodFileName(txtFileName.Text))
    {
       chartSandbox.SaveImage(txtFileName.Text, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

After inputting a valid file name into the `txtFileName` textbox, the program threw a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I have tried using different image formats and done research on other ways to save a chart image but the exception always gets thrown.

Comment: What directory are you trying to write to? Sounds like it may be a protected directory. Try  writing to Desktop or Documents to troubleshoot write access.

Comment: You were right. I didn't have the rights to save into that file. Thank you for that suggestion.